# xcode-select error while trying to install Homebrew on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, installation, homebrew

While trying to install Homebrew on macOS Sierra:

```
xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' 
Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Comment: does that directory exist?

Comment: ["_Fixed by Apple now._"](https://github.com/Homebrew/install/issues/206#issuecomment-500512545) So the [Homebrew installation](https://brew.sh/) shouldn't fail anymore.

Answer (score 9):

Yes , i have solved this error by using following steps.

1. In your terminal write command ::   xcode-select --install
2. after doing step no 1 you will get one popUp , so click on install

Comment: Works also on Ventura

Comment: On Sonoma

> Can’t install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error and the only way I could get around it was to install the Xcode command line tools manually by downloading them directly from developer.apple.com. Once installed the brew install worked without issue.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this error by installing the latest version of Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to handle this issue is to run:
`xcode-select --install`

Answer (score 1):

I tried installing Command Line Tools manually, but Command Line Tools get failed while installing. Reinstalling XCode did not help at all.

So I attempted below command helped me resolve this error on Big Sur 11.2.1 (20D74)

> sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
>
> sudo xcode-select --install
>
> /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

Comment: this worked for me in macos ventura

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can’t make comments, so I’ll post it as an answer:

If selecting the correct Xcode version for Homebrew is what you are trying to achieve, then try this:

For Xcode release:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

For Xcode beta:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
```

Answer (score 0):

Also faced this error on Sonoma 14.1.2 (23B92) and get rid of by following approach

1. In Mac terminal add : xcode-select --install
2. After it a prompt message shown, click on install

After this home-brew easily installed